# Unable to insert foreign key using Java JPA EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have a question on JPA persistence using EclipseLink.

Currently, I have the following model with one to many relationship (bi-directional).   However, when I insert rows into UseCase and PainPoint – the foreign key is always inserted as null.
Is there anything I am doing incorrect ?  I have omitted headers and setters in the code snippet.

**Console Log:**

*[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-11-17 09:41:27.719--ClientSession(1451154317)--Connection(2041265641)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--INSERT INTO PAIN_POINT (PainPointID, PainPointDescription, USECASE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
     bind => [5, Pain Point 2, null]*

**UseCase:**`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "UseCaseID")
private int UseCaseID;

@Column(name = "Description")
private String Description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="usecase", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<PainPoint> painPoints = new ArrayList<PainPoint>();
```

**PainPoint:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "PainPointID")
private int PainPointID;

@Column(name = "PainPointDescription")
private String PainPointDescription;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name="USECASE_ID", referencedColumnName="UseCaseID")
private UseCase usecase;
```

**DataLoader:**

```
UseCase useCase = new UseCase("Description 1");
PainPoint painPoint1 = new PainPoint("Pain Point 1");
useCase.getPainPoints().add(painPoint1);
em.persist(useCase);
```

Comment: How are you setting the PainPoint.usecase?  If it is null, that is what will get inserted in the foreign key.

Comment: Awesome.  That works !!  However, I am also using JAX-RS to expose it as a GET request.  I get the error - *Generating incomplete JSON*.  I will open a separate thread on that.  Thanks for the help !